# New Material Design Icon Themes - setting color

Tags: jquery, css, icons, material-design

I'm looking for a portable solution to coloring some icons. My original problem described below manifests in Chrome and Firefox on my MacBook, in Safari the colors work as expected. Commentators report that the colors work as expected in Chrome on Windows.

I have a simple jQuery Web application using Material Design icons. I can set the color of icons using CSS, all is fine. However for a few icons, in particular Folder, the new Outlined theme is much more suitable for my application, and it seems that CSS color has no effect.

There is a nice example of setting icon colors [here](https://www.tutlane.com/example/font-icons/change-material-design-icon-color-example) and if I adapt that example to read like this:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500|Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Sharp">
<title>Change Color of Google Material Design Icons Example</title>

<i class="material-icons">folder</i>
<i class="material-icons" style="font-size:40px;color:green">folder</i>
<i class="material-icons-outlined" style="font-size:50px;color:blue">folder</i>
```

On all my browsers on my MacBook I see that the standard material-icons folder takes the green color. On Safari I see the expected result: the outline of the folder is blue. However on Chrome and Firefox the outline remains black. This pattern of behaviour is true for all the icons in the extended themes Outlined, Two-Tone etc.

Suggestions please.

Comment: Converted to a snippet - it appears to do as I would expect from the code you've provided.  i.e you've told it to draw a large outlined folder icon in blue and that's exactly what it's done.  It's not clear if you're expecting the blue one to be in green or if you're expecting the `outlined` icon to be filled with blue.  Perhaps it's different on other browsers/mobile?

Comment: I don't see blue in the outlined case. I see a black outline in both Chrome and Firefox on my Mac. On what platform do you see a blue outline?

Comment: Windows 10, Chrome.  Though it's more of a purple than blue.  Try different colours - eg I tried the outline with green and it also worked.

Comment: So, some platform dependencies. (And thanks for the conversion to a snippet.)

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an older thread, but maybe some is still searching for the answer.

The outline icons seem to work as expected together with css color setting:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Sharp">

<i class="material-icons-outlined" style="color:green">home</i>
```

**Setting up the Two-tone color:**

As described above you can use the `color` css key except for materials [Two-tone](https://material.io/resources/icons/?search=comment&icon=add_comment&style=twotone) theme which seems to be glitchy ;-)

A workaround is described in one of several angular material github [issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-react/issues/730)'s by using a custom css filter. This custom filter can be generated [here](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp).

E.g.:

Html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Material+Icons|Material+Icons+Outlined|Material+Icons+Round|Material+Icons+Two+Tone|Material+Icons+Sharp">

<i class="material-icons-two-tone red">home</i>
```

css:

```
.red {
filter: invert(8%) sepia(94%) saturate(4590%) hue-rotate(358deg) brightness(101%) contrast(112%);
}
```

Attachments:

- Working Angular [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-icon-nszbyw?file=index.html)
- [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/themau5/pen/QWwaYKR)
- [Codepen CSS filter Generator](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp)

Comment: This doesn't allow you to easily set the color of the outline and the fill though. It just changes the hue of the whole icon. Not really a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since material icons are svg's you need to access the child svg element, and manipulte the svg values. They are not effected by the `color` property

```
.material-icons svg {
  fill: white; // The filling
  stroke: black; // the outline - this depends on how the svg is drawn
}
```

Comment: I will experiment as you suggest, but please note that my snippet above does show the standard Material Design folder being directly affected by the color green.